# Creating a Dictionary cookie from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

How do I add(using JavaScript) a key-value pair to the cookie?

The cookie should be read with C# code like this

```
        string userID = Request.Cookies["UserData"]["UserID"];
        string token = Request.Cookies["UserData"]["Token"];
```

It should start like this

```
document.cookie=...
```

Comment: key-value pair with the same cookie name

Comment: MDN has a large article about [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

Comment: `document.cookie="UserData=UserID=foo&Token=Bar"`. You need to add an Expires directive as well if you want a persistent cookie.

Comment: Just stick JSON data in the cookie value.

Answer (score 1):

If I set the values instead of trying to read, I get this format in the cookie:

```
name=BLA&age=100
```

So you just have to set the cookie with a `URL` format.

And you should encode the values before setting to a cookie and on the server side use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to get the value you expect.

---

This code

```
Response.Cookies["UserData"]["Name"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("BL&&&)(@!^A");
Response.Cookies["UserData"]["Age"] = "100";
```

Generates this cookie

```
Name=BL%26%26%26)(%40!%5eA&Age=100
```

And to read I am using

```
var value1 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies["UserData"]["Name"]);
var value2 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies["UserData"]["Age"]);
```

Comment: This is client side? `Response.Cookies` is not available in node.js, isn't it?